# SQL Help. 2 tables joined, need information from 2 columns from one table.

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to extract information from 2 tables (joined).

```
SELECT B.INVOICE_NUMBER,
B.BILL_TO_NAME,
B.SHIP_TO_NAME //Need this some how joined, see comment on code below
FROM ADJUSTMENTS A,
INVOICE B,
CUSTOMER_LOCATION C,
CUSTOMER_NAME D
WHERE A.INVOICE_ID = B.INVOICE_ID
AND C.CUSTOMER_ID = D.CUSTOMER_ID
AND B.BILL_ID = C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
//I want to add B.SHIP_ID = C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER as well,
//but I am unsure if it will work. Not sure how to extract information from 
//two columns from the same table that is joined to one table.
```

I researched into sub-query, but that was returning to many rows so it errored out. I am a beginner to Oracle SQL, I've tried researching but not getting the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Would be easier if you can provide sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell 100% what you are wanting, but if b.bill_id and b.ship_id have 2 different account_number's and there is only one customer_location for each account_number, then you can probably add customer_location a second time with a different alias.  If you need the customer_name record for the second customer_location then you will have to join that a second time as well.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT b.invoice_number, b.bill_to_name, b.ship_to_name
FROM adjustments a, invoice b, customer_location c,
  customer_location c2, customer_name d, customer_name d2
WHERE a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id
AND c.customer_id = d.customer_id
AND c2.customer_id = d2.customer_id
AND b.bill_id = c.account_number
AND b.ship_id = c2.account_number
```

Now your question is vague so it is hard to tell if this is what you are looking for.  Watch for multiple rows per invoice invoice number if there is more than one customer_location record per account_number, and problem solve from there if needed.  I hope this gets you closer to what you are looking for.